# TextUtils.isEmpty() method returning false for an empty string

Tags: android

I have below test which is returning false. Am I missing something?

```
TextUtils.isEmpty("")
```

Update: For some reason I am not able to answer to my question or add comment.  I am running JUNit test case and not the instrumentation test case. As, suggested I found out that the above method returns incorrect value when we don't run as an Instrumentation. 
    Thanks every one for help. I have upvoted the answer and correct comment.

Comment: Are sure you're using Andoid textutils? Are you running it in unit tests?

Comment: Are you sure that?

Comment: and cross verify looking at the source code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/text/TextUtils.java#TextUtils.isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: If you are running unit tests, Android frameworks methods are mocked, and this one in particular returns false. Use instrumentation tests to run against a full Android runtime.

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks, yes this was exactly the issue!

Comment: Did you find an answer?  facing same issue

Answer (score 4):

It should return true for empty string.
From the source of TextUtils:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable CharSequence str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
```

In tests try using something like:

```
   mockStatic(TextUtils.class);

    when(TextUtils.isEmpty(any(CharSequence.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            String string = (String) args[0];
            return (string == null || string.length() == 0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check @njzk2 comment above (should be an answer), OP is really getting `false` because the method is mocked.

Comment: See the comment dates. The additional info was not provided at the time of the answer.

Comment: Right, it's not a correction to your answer, but info for readers that get here, it's one of the first matches in google for that problem.

Comment: OP here... Yes, I wasn't aware at the time of posting that the issue was because I was running JUnit test case. Although, I haven't accepted this answer, I have given thumbs up to @damjanh!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Kotlin use [isNullOrBlank()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-null-or-blank.html) or [isNullOrEmpty()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-null-or-empty.html) methods instead. You don't need any mocking for tests.

Comment: This question was for Java, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: In the tags, I only see 'android'. Anyway, everyone should switch to Kotlin now.

Comment: True, but notice that the question was asked in 2016, when Google didn't officially support Kotlin.