# Wrong values from string empty test (java x kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm having a super weird behavior from a code that I was testing. The test I wrote was to see the behavior of the class if the Android returned an empty package name. After some debugging, I found this (consider that packageName is **empty**):

```
 val resultFromKotlin = packageName.isNullOrEmpty()
 val resultFromJava = StringUtils.isEmpty(packageName)
```

[image: Image from Andriod Studio debug]

Is this expected? Can someone tell what the deal with this?

ps1.: In the picture above, Android Studio was complaining of `isNullOrEmpty` saying that could be simplified since `packageName` can't be null at that point.

ps2.: For references:

The `StringUtils` class is written in Java as follow:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String str) {
    return str == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(str.trim());
}
```

TextUtils is also from Java, but it's part of Android library:

```
public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable CharSequence str) {
    return str == null || str.length() == 0;
}
```

This is how kotlin implements it's extension method:

```
public inline fun CharSequence?.isNullOrEmpty(): Boolean {
    contract {
        returns(false) implies (this@isNullOrEmpty != null)
    }

    return this == null || this.length == 0
}
```

**EDIT 08/11/2018**:
Just for clarification, my problem is the wrong value returned from Java, not searching for an equivalence in the test, also:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with TextUtils when running tests.

> If you are running unit tests, Android frameworks methods are mocked, and this one in particular returns false. Use instrumentation tests to run against a full Android runtime.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37664972/3271729) is where the issue is discussed.

I have tested manually by recreating the function, and it is returning true.

I would suggest using Apache Commons StringUtils implementation: [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html)

Comment: Humm.. that's explains a lot.. thanks for this answer.